System.IO.Ports and .NET7 Error: "System.IO.Ports is currently supported on Windows"
After running application in VS2022 and .NET7 I got the attached error message.

I installed NuGet package System.IO.Ports v8.0.0 . Also I tested v7.0.0 with the same result.
I use<TargetFramework>net7.0-windows7.0</TargetFramework> in project file.
What should I do? Is there a solution for this problem? Is there a missing library?
Thank you.

What OS are you targeting? You need to target a specific OS.

Are you running visual studio for mac?  Or developing in a virtual environment on a linux or mac machine?  You may need to look into using a different library that is more portable for interacting with IO ports

Why NET7 and not 6 or 8? IO.Ports works without problem on Linux (x64 and arm64) with NET 6.0 and NET 8.0.

In the project properties window, select Windows for Target OS.
Or append "-windows" to the TargetFramework property in the project file
<TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>


in project properties I have the same:
net7.0-windows7.0
The error is the same.

You may need to remove that last "7.0" so it is just "net7.0-windows". I have a feeling that it's seeing "windows7.0" as the OS version and failing because it isn't "windows"

I tested this right now. Unfortunately the same result.

Could you add the information about <TargetFramework/> to your question too.

@Max, Did you run the program on Windows? What's the value of RuntimeInformation.RuntimeIdentifier? Is there a <AppName>.deps.json file in the output directory?

The RuntimeInformation.RuntimeIdentifier shows "win10-x86" .
What about the *.deps.json file? What information?

The file should contain the path to the implementation assembly, something like "runtimes/win/lib/net7.0/System.IO.Ports.dll": {...}. If you can find that dll, try to copy it to the output directory to overwrite the original one. See if this works.
